# Complex Maven Project and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a [maven-based Java project](https://github.com/JMRI/JMRI) that includes some code that is generated using javacc. Other Java code in the project has a dependency on the generated code.

The Maven phases `generate-sources` and `compile` both work without issue, however, Eclipse will not successfully build the project until I manually trigger `mvn generate-sources`.

The generated sources are placed in their own folder and own "Java Build Path" such that Eclipse recognizes that sources are missing.

Question: Is there a way to have Eclipse automatically run `mvn generate-sources` when it recognizes that a build path is missing?

Comment: The clean solution would be to  wire up the maven phases such that the sources are generated during compilation.

Comment: @Turing85 I guess this is not the issue, because the named phases (`generate-sources`, `compile`) _are_ run during the normal build. I suspect you need to tell Eclipse that the folder you generate your sources to is also a source folder so that Eclipse can handle that. I don' know the mechanism for that, but I guess google can help.

Comment: I have Eclipse configured such that the folder I generate the sources to is a source folder, but Eclipse refuses to run its automatic build until after `mvn generate-sources` is run with a "can't find sources" error.